# Python - Why does using map cost more time than iterating through the list?

Tags: python

```
from timeit import Timer
def m1():
    l = range(100000)
    for i in l:
        l[i] *= 2

def m2():
    l = range(100000)
    l = map(lambda i:i*2,l)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    t1 = Timer('m1()','from __main__ import m1')
    print t1.timeit(100)

    t2 = Timer('m2()','from __main__ import m2')
    print t2.timeit(100)
```

the time m2 cost is more than m1 cost, could you explain why?

and what the implementation of map function, does it use iterator?

Thanks

Comment: You are comparing apples to oranges. One is building a new list, the other is modifying a list in-place. So that will certainly affect the runtime.

Comment: You should call your lambda function on each element of your list, instead of doing `l[i] *= 2`; that'll slow `m1` down as well.

Comment: And yes, operators are faster than function calls.

Comment: You can also use `xrange()` in the `m2` as you don't need a list for `map`.

Comment: I know xrange is lazy init, can save some memory, but i don't think use xrange will save the time,right?

Comment: `xrange` can *certainly* save time. If you don't actually need the list, it saves the time building the list and expensive memory allocation. Of course, if you need the list, time will not be saved.

Answer (score 0):

In `m2` the computation is performed via a function call to the lambda function. Even though it is a single line, it still qualifies as a function and thus has the cost of the function call.

Additionally the `m2` creates a new list and assigns it to the variable `l`, the cost of the creation of that new list also needs to be taken into account.

In `m1` there is simply the cost of the computation, hence `m1` ends up faster.

`m1` steps :

1. Create list in variable `l`
2. Multiple each item in list `l` with 2

`m2` steps :

1. Create list in variable `l`
2. Create new list via lambda function calls iterating through list `l`
3. Assign the new list to variable `l`